# EMR Cluster utilization

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, amazon-emr

I have a 20 mode c4.4xlarge cluster to run a spark job. Each node is a 16 vCore, 30 GiB memory, EBS only storage EBS Storage:32 GiB machine.

Since each node has 16 vCore, I understand that maximum number of executors are 16*20 > 320 executors. Total memory available is 20(#nodes)*30 ~ 600GB. Assigning 1/3rd to system operations, I have 400 GB of Memory to process my data in-memory. Is this the right understanding.

Also, Spark History shows non-uniform distribution of input and shuffle. I believe the processing is not distributed evenly across executors. I pass these config parameters in my spark-submit -

```
> —-conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true  —-conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=20
```

Executor summary from spark history UI also shows that data distribution load is completely skewed, and I am not using the cluster in the best way. How can I distribute my load in a better way -

[image]

Comment: This was done running a single job in the cluster. However, leveraging Fair-scheduler has increased overall parallelism and cluster utilization, thus giving me better throughput